# Meaning of the colors bar under the of clips you might watch in YouTube

Tags: youtube

I think the title describes all. They will show more obvious when the thumbnails haven't done loading yet. The picture following here will describe it better.

[image: image description]

I use a userscript named [YouTube Center](https://github.com/YePpHa/YouTubeCenter/wiki).

Comment: May be its nothing but the custom video progress here take a look at this source https://userstyles.org/styles/95280/youtube-custom-colors-video-progress-bar

Comment: I don't think so. Those bar still appear when I disable the script. Maybe the like/dislike bar?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What OP's image shows is a like/dislike bar put there by an extension (like YouTube Center). Since getting likes/dislikes costs API quota, it doesn't load them always and displays a purple bar instead.

YouTube however now has a similar feature where they use a red/grey bar to show how much of the video you have watched. [image: It looks like this.]